# Which indices are FALSE?

Tags: r

`which()` conveniently gives all the indices which are `TRUE` in `x`. What is a simple way to get all the indices of `x` which are `FALSE`?

Comment: `which(!x)` ...

Comment: @HongOoi , post as answer ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sample data

```
x <- c(T,T,F,F)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

which function gives indices where we have TRUE value

```
which(x)
[1] 1 2
```

If we need to populate indices for only FALSE values

```
which(!x)
[1] 3 4
```

we can also bring false values as output as

```
 !which(x)
 [1] FALSE FALSE
```